# Vue3 emit data to parent -> data not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

i have the following problem.

I have a parent component where I store data from child components.

In the child components, I emit data to the parent and the parent is storing it into data.

This works for the first time, but after a while the storing is no longer possible. It feels like the data in the parent is not updating. The emit event is still working.

The following method is triggered by the emit:

```
updateData(value) {
  passData = value.daten;
  var stepName = value.stepName;

  if (this.formData[stepName]) {
    for (var i = 0; i < passData.length; i++) {
      
      var found = this.formData[stepName].find(
        (item) => item.question === passData[i].question
      );
      if (!found) {
        this.formData[stepName].push(passData[i]);
      } else {
        found.content = passData[i].content;
      }
    }
  } else {
    this.formData[stepName] = passData;
  }
},
```

This is working, but just for the first time. No Errors. Feels like something about Vue3 is different in case of interactive vars.

Comment: It may be overkill if this is the only place it would be useful, but this could be a good use case for state management.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Never used the state management before but this works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding stage management. It works fine and its the better solution!